# Add new column headers and data to csv file from sql query c#

Tags: c#, sql, datatable

I'm in the middle of creating a console application in C# which extracts data from a few separate sql queries and displays the data in a csv file.

The column headers come from the file ExtractDocument.cs in a public record:

```
 public record ExtractDocument
    {
        [Name("ItemID")]
        public Guid ItemId { get; set; }
       
        [Name("ItemDetailID")]
        public Guid ItenDetailId { get; set; }
        public string? Number { get; set; }
        public string? Title { get; set; }

        public string? Status { get; set; }
       
        [Name("Item Type")]
        public string? ItemType { get; set; }
        public int MajorRevisionNumber { get; set; }
        public int MinorRevisionNumber { get; set; }
        public int RevisionNumberOffset { get; set; }
        public string? CreatedDate { get; set; } 

        public string? ReleaseDate  { get; set; }
        public string? WithdrawnDate { get; set; }

        [Name("Process Owner")]
        public string? ProcessOwner { get; set; }
        public string? Reviewer { get; set; }
        public string? Approver { get; set; }

        public string? Author { get; set; }

        [Name("Admin Owner")]
        public string? AdminOwner { get; set; }
    }
```

The csv file is then made up in the file RecordRespository.cs like so:

```
 public class RecordRepository : IRecordRepository
    {

        private readonly string _connectionString;

        public RecordRepository(string connectionString)
        {
            _connectionString = connectionString;
        }

        public List<ExtractDocument> GetExtractDocuments()
        {
            var items = GetExtractData();
            
            return items.Select().Select(x => new ExtractDocument
            {
                ItemId = x.Field<Guid>("ItemId"),
                ItenDetailId = x.Field<Guid>("ItemDetailId"),
                Number = x.Field<string>("Number"),
                Status = x.Field<string>("Status"),
                ItemType = x.Field<string>("Item Type"),
                MajorRevisionNumber = x.Field<int>("MajorRevisionNumber"),
                MinorRevisionNumber = x.Field<int>("MinorRevisionNumber"),
                RevisionNumberOffset = x.Field<int>("RevisionNumberOffset"),
                CreatedDate = x.Field<DateTime?>("CreatedDate")?.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"),
                ReleaseDate = x.Field<DateTime?>("Releasedate")?.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"),
                WithdrawnDate = x.Field<DateTime?>("WithdrawnDate")?.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"),
                ProcessOwner = x.Field<string>("Process Owner"),
                Reviewer = x.Field<string>("Reviewer"),
                Approver = x.Field<string>("Approver"),
                Author = x.Field<string>("Author"),
                AdminOwner = x.Field<string>("Admin Owner")
            }).ToList();
        }

        private DataTable GetTable(string sql, SqlParameter[]? paras = null)
        {
            var dt = new DataTable();
            using var cnn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
            using var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn);

            if (paras != null && paras.Length > 0)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddRange(paras);
            }

            var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);

            return dt;
        }

        public DataTable GetExtractData()
        {
            var itemsTable = new DataTable();
            var roleHoldersTable = new DataTable();
            var customPropertiesTable = new DataTable();

            using var cnn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);

            AddDataToTable(ItemsQuery, cnn, itemsTable);
            AddDataToTable(RoleHoldersQuery, cnn, roleHoldersTable);
            AddDataToTable(CustomPropertiesQuery, cnn, customPropertiesTable);

            var getProcessOwner = SetColumnData(itemsTable, roleHoldersTable, "Process Owner", "HolderTitle", GetDetailIdFilter("OwnershipRoleTitle", "Process Owner"));
            var getReviewer = SetColumnData(getProcessOwner, roleHoldersTable, "Reviewer", "HolderTitle", GetDetailIdFilter("OwnershipRoleTitle", "Reviewer"));
            var getApprover = SetColumnData(getReviewer, roleHoldersTable, "Approver", "HolderTitle", GetDetailIdFilter("OwnershipRoleTitle", "Approver"));
            var getAuthor = SetColumnData(getApprover, roleHoldersTable, "Author", "HolderTitle", GetDetailIdFilter("OwnershipRoleTitle", "Author"));
            var getAdminOwner = SetColumnData(getAuthor, roleHoldersTable, "Admin Owner", "HolderTitle", GetDetailIdFilter("OwnershipRoleTitle", "Admin Owner"));

            return getAdminOwner;
        }

        private static DataTable AddDataToTable(string query, SqlConnection connection, DataTable tableToFill)
        {
            using var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection);

            var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            adapter.Fill(tableToFill);

            return tableToFill;
        }

        private static Func<DataRow, string> GetDetailIdFilter(string secondColumnName, string secondColumnCondition)
        {
            return row => string.Format("ItemDetailID='{0}' AND {1} = '{2}'", Convert.ToString(row["ItemDetailID"]), secondColumnName, secondColumnCondition);
        }

        private static DataTable SetColumnData(
            DataTable targetTable, DataTable sourceTable,
            string columnToCreate, string sourceColumn, Func<DataRow, string> rowFilter)
        {
            targetTable.Columns.Add(columnToCreate, typeof(string));

            foreach (DataRow row in targetTable.Rows)
            {
                DataRow[] rowsTarget;

                rowsTarget = sourceTable.Select(rowFilter(row));

                if (rowsTarget !=null && rowsTarget.Length > 0)
                {
                    var values = rowsTarget.Select(r => r[sourceColumn].ToString()).ToList();
                    row[columnToCreate] = string.Join(", ", values);
                }
                else
                {
                    row[columnToCreate] = "";
                    LogMissingData(columnToCreate, row["Title"]?.ToString() ?? "", row["ItemId"].ToString() ?? "");
                }
            }
            return targetTable;
        }

        private static void LogMissingData(string column, string rowTitle, string itemId)
        {
            ErrorLogging.ErrorList.Add(new ErrorLogging()
            {
                ErrorType = "Warning",
                Relation = "Database - to do with column: " + column,
                Message = $"Data not found for document with the title: {rowTitle} and the itemId: {itemId}"
            });
        }

        private const string ItemsQuery = @"
SELECT 
  id.ItemId, id.ItemDetailID, id.Number, id.Title,
  id.Status, I.Type AS 'Item Type', id.MajorRevisionNumber, id.MinorRevisionNumber,
  RevisionNumberOffset = ISNULL(id.RevisionNumberOffset, 0), id.CreatedDate, id.ReleaseDate,
  id.WithdrawnDate
FROM AgilityItemView v
JOIN ItemDetail id
    ON id.ItemDetailID = v.ItemDetailId
JOIN Item i
    on i.ItemID = v.ItemId";

        private const string RoleHoldersQuery = @"
SELECT 
    ID.ItemID ,
    ID.ItemDetailID,
    OwnershipRoleTitle = IOR.Title, 
    HolderTitle = P.Title,
    VersionRank = P.VersionRank
FROM 
dbo.ItemDetailOwnershipRole IDOR
INNER JOIN ItemDetail ID
    ON ID.ItemDetailID = IDOR.ItemDetailID
INNER JOIN dbo.ItemOwnershipRole IOR
    ON IDOR.ItemOwnershipRoleID = IOR.ItemOwnershipRoleID
INNER JOIN  dbo.ItemDetailOwnershipRoleHolder IDOH
    ON IDOH.ItemDetailOwnershipRoleID = IDOR.ItemDetailOwnershipRoleID
INNER JOIN  dbo.AgilityItemView P
ON IDOH.ItemOwnershipRoleHolderItemID = P.ItemID
WHERE IOR.Title IN ('Process Owner', 'Reviewer', 'Approver', 'Author', 'Admin Owner')";

        private const string CustomPropertiesQuery = @"
SELECT id.ItemID,
id.ItemDetailID
, cp.Title, cpi.ItemTitle
FROM AgilityItemView v
JOIN ItemDetail id
    ON id.ItemDetailID = v.ItemDetailId
JOIN CustomPropertyItemReference cpir
    ON cpir.ItemDetailID = id.ItemDetailID
JOIN CustomPropertyItem cpi
    ON cpi.CustomPropertyItemID = cpir.ReferenceItemID
JOIN CustomProperty cp
    ON cp.CustomPropertyID = cpi.CustomPropertyID";
    }
}
```

This works by creating a data table and then adding a new column with the new value in the row based on matching ItemDetailIds from the queries, if that makes sense?

The issue I'm having is I do not have access to the database this application will be running against so just having to use something else for the time being. What I have in the public record ExtractDocument are the column headers I know 100% will be there.

For the query:

```
        private const string CustomPropertiesQuery = @"
SELECT id.ItemID,
id.ItemDetailID
, cp.Title, cpi.ItemTitle
FROM AgilityItemView v
JOIN ItemDetail id
    ON id.ItemDetailID = v.ItemDetailId
JOIN CustomPropertyItemReference cpir
    ON cpir.ItemDetailID = id.ItemDetailID
JOIN CustomPropertyItem cpi
    ON cpi.CustomPropertyItemID = cpir.ReferenceItemID
JOIN CustomProperty cp
    ON cp.CustomPropertyID = cpi.CustomPropertyID";
```

I need to add more column headers to the csv file based on the distinct values that come from "cp.Title", since I do not know what those values will be I have just been told to have the application grab each unique one rather than specify specific ones like I have done in the RoleHoldersQuery.

I have managed to do this by doing the following:

```
public List<string> GetADPTitles()
{
    var customPropertiesTable = new DataTable();

    using var cnn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);

    AddDataToTable(CustomPropertiesQuery, cnn, customPropertiesTable);

    List<string>uniqueADPTitles = new List<string>();
    foreach (DataRow dr in customPropertiesTable.Rows)
    {
        if (!uniqueADPTitles.Contains((string)dr["ADPTitle"]))
        {
            uniqueADPTitles.Add((string)dr["ADPTitle"]);
        }
    }

    return uniqueADPTitles;
}
```

I have then also created a second method for getting the row values for the columns as well like so:

```
public List<string> ExtractADPData()
{
    var customPropertiesTable = new DataTable();

    using var cnn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);

    AddDataToTable(CustomPropertiesQuery, cnn, customPropertiesTable);

    var items = GetExtractData();
    var titles = GetADPTitles();

    List<DataTable> ADPDataTables = new List<DataTable>();
    foreach (var title in titles)
    { 
            ADPDataTables.Add(SetColumnData(items, customPropertiesTable, title, "ItemTitle", GetDetailIdFilter("ADPTitle", title)));
    }

   List<string>test = new List<string>();

    test.Add(ADPDataTables.ToList().ToString());
    return test;
}
```

And then in my Runner.cs file (which calls all the method I do the following:

```
        var extractData = repo.GetExtractDocuments();

        ExportLog.SaveFile(exportFile, extractData);

        Console.WriteLine(extractData.GetType());

        List<string> records = repo.GetADPTitles().ToList();

        List<string> adpData = repo.ExtractADPData();                
       
        foreach ( var record in records)
        {
            var filePath = exportFile;

            var csv1 = File.ReadLines(filePath.ToString()).Select((line, index) => index == 0
                ? line + "," + record.ToString()
                : line + "," + adpData.ToString()).ToList();


            File.WriteAllLines(filePath.ToString(), csv1); 
        }
```

This kind of works, I get the new columns added to the csv file and the rows are generated but each row has a value of: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]

rather than the actual data itself. Where have I gone wrong and how can I get the actual value rather than what is currently getting displayed?

Comment: No, it's not possible. You need to go about this in a different way; put your extra fields in a dictionary and write them to CSV from there

Comment: okay I'll look into doing that, thank you for the advice